# Getting "Removal of package SYMCnbclt was unsuccessful. Aborting..." error while insatlling Netbackup in solaris 10

Tags: backup, solaris, solaris-10

I am trying to install NetBackup_7.6.0.1 client in solaris 10 server. But I am getting "Removal of package SYMCnbclt was unsuccessful. Aborting..." error.

I  have checked for space and I have sufficient space in the server to install the client.

```
server1:/Netbackup/NBU_7.6_clients/7.6.0.1/NetBackup_7.6.0.1_CLIENTS1# ./install
Symantec Installation Script
Copyright 1993 - 2013 Symantec Corporation, All Rights Reserved.


    Installing NetBackup Client Software
Please review the SYMANTEC SOFTWARE LICENSE AGREEMENT located on
the installation media before proceeding.  The agreement includes
details on the NetBackup Product Improvement Program.

For NetBackup installation and upgrade information specific to your
platform and to find out if your installed EEBs or hot fixes are
contained in this release, check out the Symantec Operations Readiness
Tools (SORT) Installation and Upgrade Checklist and Hot fix and EEB
Release Auditor, respectively, at https://sort.symantec.com/netbackup.

Do you wish to continue? [y,n] (y) y
Running preinstall checker...
Running preinstall checker...
ok nb_7601_hotfix_auditor: No potential for regression of hotfixes or `EEBs was detected.`



Do you want to install the NetBackup client software for this client? [y,n] (y) y

This package will install Solaris/Solaris10 client.

NetBackup client is currently at release level 7.1.0.4.

This package will install NetBackup client 7.6.0.1.

Client binaries are located in /Netbackup/NBU_7.6_clients/7.6.0.1`/NetBackup_7.6.0.1_CLIENTS1/NBClients/anb/Clients/usr/openv/netbackup/client/Solaris/Solaris10.`

Checking for SYMCpddea package...


Package SYMCpddea found.

NetBackup Deduplication software is installed.

NetBackup Deduplication is not yet configured.

Terminating NetBackup and/or Media Manager processes.


Saving client binaries for Solaris/Solaris10.

Installing PBX...
Same version is already installed. Nothing to upgrade for package VRTSpbx
Installation log located here: /var/tmp/installpbx-6933-062416115732.log


Unpacking SYMCnbclt package.
Checking for pre-existing SYMCnbclt package.
Removing pre-existing SYMCnbclt package.


ERROR:   Removal of package SYMCnbclt was unsuccessful.
     Aborting...


========== Unpacking package ==========
x SYMCnbclt.pkg, 509976064 bytes, 996047 tape blocks
x .pkg_defaults, 160 bytes, 1 tape blocks


== Checking for pre-existing package ==
application SYMCnbclt NetBackup Client

==== Removing pre-existing package ====
./cp_to_client: pkgrm: not found


ERROR:   A failure was detected running
     /Netbackup/NBU_7.6_clients/7.6.0.1/NetBackup_7.6.0.1_CLIENTS1`/NBClients/anb/Clients/usr/openv/netbackup/client/Solaris/Solaris10/cp_to_client ukgbdcbkppw051 server1 /tmp/install_trace.6413`

File /usr/openv/tmp/install_trace.6413 contains a trace of this install.
That file can be deleted after you are sure the install was successful.
```

Please help me to install netbackup on the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is suspicious:  `./cp_to_client: pkgrm: not found`  What is the result from `which pkgrm`?  Is there a `/usr/sbin/pkgrm` on your system?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on unix.stackexchange.com instead as a Unix system admin question, not programming.